# Facebook cordova login error : 'Failed to instantiate module facebookApp due to..'

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, cordova

Hi I am a beginner programmer trying to integrate facebook login using cordova. I followed this pretty recent guide [shown here](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-integrate-facebook-login-into-a-cordova-based-app/), and have copy pasted the code word for word in a new cordova project. I have had experience with Jquery but this is my first time encountering both Angular and ionic.
Here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <title>Facebook Login</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

        <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/driftyco/ng-cordova/master/dist/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/nraboy/ng-cordova-oauth/master/dist/ng-cordova-oauth.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova_plugins.js"></script>
        <!-- added the directories myself below -->
        <script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-app="facebookApp">
            <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
            </div>   
        </div>

        <div data-role="page" id="home">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Login</h1>
            </div>

            <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
                <p>You need to login to view your Facebook profile information</p>
                <p>V1.0.1</p>
                <a target="_blank" href="#" onclick="login()" style="text-decoration: none"><button>Login using Facebook</button></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div data-role="page" id="profile">
            <div data-role="header">
                <a target="_blank" href="#home" class="ui-btn ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-left">Home</a>
                <h1>Profile</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="main" class="ui-content" id="listTable"></div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            angular.module("facebookApp", ["ionic", "ngCordova"]).controller("mainCtrl", ["$scope", "$cordovaOauth", "$http", function($scope, $cordovaOauth, $http) {
                window.cordovaOauth = $cordovaOauth;
                window.http = $http;
            }]);

            function login()
            {
                facebookLogin(window.cordovaOauth, window.http);
            }

            function facebookLogin($cordovaOauth, $http)
            alert($cordovaOauth);
            alert($http);
            {
                $cordovaOauth.facebook("201821216900862", ["email", "public_profile"], {redirect_uri: "http://localhost/callback"}).then(function(result){
                    displayData($http, result.access_token);
                },  function(error){
                        alert("Error: " + error);
                });
            }

            function displayData($http, access_token)
            {
                $http.get("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/me", {params: {access_token: access_token, fields: "name,gender,location,picture", format: "json" }}).then(function(result) {
                    var name = result.data.name;
                    var gender = result.data.gender;
                    var location = result.data.location;
                    var picture = result.data.picture;
                    var html = '<table id="table" data-role="table" data-mode="column" class="ui-responsive"><thead><tr><th>Field</th><th>Info</th></tr></thead><tbody>';
                    html = html + "<tr><td>" + "Name" + "</td><td>" + name + "</td></tr>";
                    html = html + "<tr><td>" + "Gender" + "</td><td>" + gender + "</td></tr>";
                    html = html + "<tr><td>" + "Picture" + "</td><td><img src='" + picture.data.url + "' /></td></tr>";
                    html = html + "</tbody></table>";

                    document.getElementById("listTable").innerHTML = html;
                    $.mobile.changePage($("#profile"), "slide", true, true);
                }, function(error) {
                    alert("There was a problem getting your profile.  Check the logs for details.");
                    console.log(error);
                });
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Mutliple errors was returned by eclipse, but the most important errors being,
 `Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module facebookApp due to:`
and
`Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'facebookApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.`
Anularjs also produced a webpage for the error [shown here](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=facebookApp&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:nomod%5D%20Module%20%27facebookApp%27%20is%20not%20available!%20You%20either%20misspelled%20the%20module%20name%20or%20forgot%20to%20load%20it.%20If%20registering%20a%20module%20ensure%20that%20you%20specify%20the%20dependencies%20as%20the%20second%20argument.%0Ahttp:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.5.3%2F$injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3DfacebookApp%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Fcode.ionicframework.com%2Fnightly%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js:13437:12%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Fcode.ionicframework.com%2Fnightly%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js:15403:17%0A%20%20%20%20at%20ensure%20(http:%2F%2Fcode.ionicframework.com%2Fnightly%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js:15327:38)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20module%20(http:%2F%2Fcode.ionicframework.com%2Fnightly%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js:15401:14)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Fcode.ionicframework.com%2Fnightly%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js:17893:22%0A%20%20%20%20at%20forEach%20(http:%2F%2Fcode.ionicframework.com%2Fnightly%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js:13690:20)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20loadModules%20(http:%2F%2Fcode.ionicframework.com%2Fnightly%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js:17877:5)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20createInjector%20(http:%2F%2Fcode.ionicframework.com%2Fnightly%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js:17799:19)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Fcode.ionicframework.com%2Fnightly%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js:15079:20%0A%20%20%20%20at%20bootstrap%20(http:%2F%2Fcode.ionicfrahttp:%2F%2Fcode.ionicframework.com%2Fnightly%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js:17916) and suggested that this line of code:`angular.module("facebookApp", ["ionic", "ngCordova"]).controller("mainCtrl", ["$scope", "$cordovaOauth", "$http", function($scope, $cordovaOauth, $http) {` caused the errors. Also, my angular is at version 1.5.8 which does not support this action the code is trying to do. The website suggest I add it as a dependency to my application's top-level module which I have no idea how to.

Any input or sugestion will be appreciated thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Script order is really important.

Try to reorder them like this

```
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/driftyco/ng-cordova/master/dist/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/nraboy/ng-cordova-oauth/master/dist/ng-cordova-oauth.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova_plugins.js"></script>
```

Is it normal to have 2 angular.js injection ?

Comment: Hey, the error is still here after re-arranging and I added both .js meself, doesn't work when I remove it too, still, thanks for your input!!

Answer (score 0):

i overcome this issue so solution is this:
-as you open index.php in chrome you can probably see something like error:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $cordovaProvider http://....

That is caused by old angular module part - if you look closely on that part. There is header line that including parts `ionic`, `ngCordova` but in new version `ngCordova` was divided to two files. So basically what you have to do is change angular header to this:

```
angular.module("facebookApp",["ionic","ngCordova","ngCordovaOauth"]).controller("mainCtrl", ["$scope", "$cordovaOauth", "$http"], function($scope, $cordovaOauth, $http) {
...
//your app code
...
})
```

Take notice of `ngCordovaOauth` was added to header. That was your problem. :] Have nice day! Hope it helped, you are first i have ever helped on stackowerflow.